# Sending array containing multiple types via Postman and C#

Tags: c#, postman

This is the requirement of the api:

```
"merchant_uid": "{{merchant_uid}}",
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "price": 100,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "return_url": "https://platform.example.com/return/",
    "notify_url": "https://platform.example.com/notify/",
    "total_price": 100
```

I tried putting everyhing into postman like so

[image]

But this returns an 400 bad request.

I also tried doing this via c# but I cant figure out to give it a type containing numbers and strings (i received the 400 bad request: products must be in array):

```
var products = new
{
    name = "test",
    price = 100,
    quantity = 1
};



var postModel = new
{
    merchant_uid = merchant_uid,
    products = products,
    return_url = return_url,
    notify_url = notify_url,
    total_price = total_price,
};

var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, postModel);
```

So neither approach works.

Can you fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you got Product and PostModel classes defined ? When you're creating postModel you can create a list of products with one item like so: `products  = new List<Product>{products},`

Comment: Fieldnames are case sensitive. Are you sure it shouldn't be "Name" instead of "name"?

Comment: no they are annonymous. can u provid code sample? im not familiar with that syntax. And i am sure it is "name" :)

Comment: possibly url might be excepting an array. please check by posting an array of object

Answer (score 0):

If your controller method is a [HttpPost] method, you should send your entry as Json.
To do it:

- Choose **Post** request
- In body section, choose **raw** and **Json** type
  See the picture below:

  [image]

Comment: Thank you, I figured out how to do it in postman but still it isnt working in c# code. It says products must have a name...